# nextjs strapi - form data post request causing 500 error

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi, http-status-code-500

I am trying to make POST request using formdata to strapi backend from nextjs app and receiving
500 error.
Here's the code

```
const token = Cookie.get("jwt") && Cookie.get("jwt");

  const [product, setProduct] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    image: "",
    category: "",
    price: "",
  });

  const { name, description, image, category, price } = product;

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const data = {
        name,
        description,
        price,
        category,
      };

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("files.image", image);     
      formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));

      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/products`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        body: formData,
      });
      const result = await res.json();
      if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

This is the error I am getting back

```
{
statusCode: 500, error: "Internal Server Error", message: "An internal server error occurred"}
error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "An internal server error occurred"
statusCode: 500
}
```

Any idea what is causing 500 internal server error?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tested your api endpoints with postman or httpie or something like that ?

Comment: yes, but got same 500 error in postman too

Comment: So this error doesn't come from next.js, actually the code what have you delivered may be ok, you need to search inside strapi documentations and first of all test this with postman. TIP: Never, never test your api endpoints with frontend

Comment: I got it, category field requires ID, I was passing name. Thank you